# What is the white fungus growing on my Hibiscus and how do I treat it?

Tags: fungus, hibiscus

I want to ask the question regarding the white fungus I am seeing on my plant. I don't know what to do about it, it grows with the plant. I have used Neem oil to cure it but it doesn't help, rather it withered my plant.

I would like to know what I should do to get rid of that fungus.[image][image]

Comment: Why do we have that rule, Sue?  One picture for newbies?  I am really worried about the use of NEEM and burning leaves?  I am thinking he is dealing with powdery mildew as it is that time of year.  Zeba, also let us know how much NEEM to how much water, when (bright sun, nighttime the best time to spray) you sprayed it, how long ago, how many applications?  You did mix it with water, yes?  Please send a picture, replacing this pic of the flower with vegetation and try to tell us exactly what you've done.  How did you think it was fungus?  Why did you choose NEEM?  Did you use anything else?

Comment: @stormy Ok so when I saw that white matter growing on my hibiscus plant, I googled about it and came to know that generally Hibiscus plants have this fungus. After that I searched for it's treatment and then I found this Neem OIl. The recipe #3 on this link is what that I had used:[link] (http://eyeonlifemag.com/a-lovely-garden/what-is-neem-oil-and-how-to-make-neem-oil.html) I had sprayed it in day time of winters and after some days it withered. It's winter in now in India.

Comment: Is there a bit of webbing at the stem of the leaves? I can't see it clearly, could you confirm this?

Comment: @Stephie No, Stem is clear. It has no webbing, the fungus could be seen on the leaves or on the buds.

Comment: I know I am seeing webbing.  See the little white elongated dots?  They are hanging in the 'air'...on webs.

Comment: Take a picture of the underside of these leaves...please!!

Answer (score 2):

You've got WHITE FLY for sure.  Look under the leaves as well.  Instead of spraying NEEM solution, what I do is make a big 3 or 5 gallon pail of water mixed with 1 oz NEEM per gallon.  Take a paper plate and slice the paper plate to the center.  Place the paper plate over the potting soil with the stem at the center, turn upside down and swish the plant in the NEEM solution.  Throw a little of the solution on the top of the soil.  Where is this plant living?  You might have to do a little bit of housecleaning in the area to kill all the white fly.  Looks like you have spider mite as well. This will treat both!  Where this plant lives there will be all kinds of white fly stages and spider mite that will reinfect your plant.  Clean and expect to do additional dunkings.  Check your plants in a week or two at the most and if you see any sign, dunk again...new solution of water and NEEM.  Wipe surfaces around your plants environment with bleach.  This should work for any fungus as well.  White Fly and spider mite cause optimal conditions for fungus with their excrement + bacteria = honey dew, loved by fungus.  Fungus will go bye bye when you take care of the insects.

Comment: And I would repot this plant with new soil right out of the bag, clean that pot with bleach.  Don't allow leaves/debris to sit on the top of the soil.

Comment: I wasn't able to pull up any other photographs.  You do have white fly and usually spider mite is included.  Those webs are very tiny.  I am seeing those little white dots floating in the air which means webbing.  Don't spray, mix 1 oz per gallon and dunk the entire plant, swish a bit.  NEEM is not some easy peasy no worry pesticide.  Check its smell!  Read that label FIVE times.  That is what us Pesticide Applicators are taught.  NEEM is pretty cool as far as a Pesticide is concerned.  Remember you will probably have to repeat the dunking at least one more time.

Comment: Ohk.. Thanks. So I have to do this once in a week?

Comment: No.  You only need to do this IF you see insects again.  There is never any particular schedule you should do with plants anyway.  I am serious, plants are each so individual with their needs.  Do  you have other house plants?  If you do, you'll probably find they've got white  fly and spider mites as well.  The more you get to know your plants the more you will hear them talking to you.  I can be sitting in my doctor's office and the plant across the room will SCREAM.  Or I'll be up and checking it out as if it did!  This little plant caused you to look closer and I am not too woo woo, grins!

Comment: Promise me that you will read that information on your NEEM bottle!  Each and everytime you need to use it.  If you have any questions about that label, please write!  This is the number one thing we are taught to do as Pesticide Applicators.  All these decades of caring for plants and lawns, I could count on one hand the amount of times I had to used labeled pesticides.  Think of pesticides as 'bandaids' on problems that could have been prevented.  Look up these critters and get to know them and do the same with any plant in your care.

Comment: Actually, I have a Neem tree in my house. SO I was thinking of soaking it's leaves overnight in water. How about this? Will it work same as the NEEM pesticide?